# Why do I get TypeError when I try adding express to my first react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have created my first react app using `npx create-react-app my-app` and started it. Now I want to add express into this react app. Hence I have added the below line in my `index.js`

> var express = require('express')

Here is what my whole index.js looks like. The above is the only line that I have added, rest is exactly same as what I got from `create-react-app`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


var express = require('express')
// const helmet = require('helmet')
// const app = express()
// app.use(helmet())

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The error that I'm getting is `TypeError: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference`. The below is the full stacktrace of the error that I'm seeing in browser. And please note that there are no compilation issues.

```
×
TypeError: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference
Anonymous function
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:58
  55 |  */
  56 | 
  57 | 
> 58 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype);
  59 | /**
  60 |  * Module exports.
  61 |  * @public
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1
> 1 | /*!
  2 |  * express
  3 |  * Copyright(c) 2009-2013 TJ Holowaychuk
  4 |  * Copyright(c) 2014-2015 Douglas Christopher Wilson
View compiled
__webpack_require__
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^
  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^
  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:27
__webpack_require__
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^
  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^
  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/express/index.js
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/node_modules/express/index.js:10
__webpack_require__
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^
  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^
  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./src/index.js
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/src/index.js:8
   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
   7 | 
>  8 | var express = require('express')
   9 | // const helmet = require('helmet')
  10 | 
  11 | // const app = express()
View compiled
__webpack_require__
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^
  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^
  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:388:1
__webpack_require__
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^
  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^
  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
webpackJsonpCallback
mylocaldrivepath/react/my-app/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^
  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
Global code
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:2
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Any help on fixing this issue is greatly appreciated !

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: I have tried opening my localhost from chrome & Edge and got the error on both. 

Chrome says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` and Edge says `TypeError: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: okay sorry i didnt get it at first, you are adding express directly in you client app, express is used to build backend, you need to create a separate project for that

Comment: ok. I actually want to add security headers to the responses that's returned by my react app. Hence I thought of using express js, so that I can add response headers  using it. Is there any other way of adding response headers to the react responses !!

Answer (score 0):

Typically `express` is placed outside of the src folder to serve your compiled client-side code; meanwhile, `webpack-dev-server` creates a development server and compiles code on the fly; so in this case, since you're using the `create-react-app` and not utilizing server-side rendering, then you don't need express (for development).

Instead, once you've compiled your code for production (via `npm run build`), you'll need some way to serve the assets. Typically, you'll have an `app.js` file that sits outside of the `src` folder and that will serve your compiled production folder (`dist` or `build`):

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const currentDirectory = process.cwd(); // current directory

app.use(express.static("dist")); // express will serve up production assets
app.get("*", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(resolve(`${currentDirectory}/dist/index.html`))
); // express will serve up the front-end index.html file if it doesn't recognize the route

app.listen(8080, err => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(`\nYour application is running on port 8080}\n`);
  } else {
    console.err(`\nUnable to start server: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

For example:

```
├── dist
|   ├── css
|   |   ├── main.[contenthash:8].css
|   |   └── main.[contenthash:8].css.map
|   ├── js
|   |   ├── main.[hash].js
|   |   └── main.[hash].js.map
|   ├── media
|   |   └── [hash].[ext]
|   └── favicon.ico
|   └── index.html
|
├── public
|   ├── favicon.ico
|   └── index.html
|
├── src
|   ├── actions
|   ├── components
|   ├── containers
|   ├── images
|   ├── pages
|   ├── reducers
|   ├── root
|   ├── routes
|   ├── styles
|   ├── types
|   ├── utils
|   └── index.js
|
└── app.js
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the answer. I'm going to try this out now. 
Actually when I created my app using `create-react-app` I have an `app.js` inside `src` folder. Do you want me to move that outside of  `src` or create a new one outside `src` and copy the code that you have provided.

Comment: Outside. The src folder will be compiled into a single or multiple js files depending upon size. Express will then serve those files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it!

I was using Express.js and Node.js for backend and React.js for frontend and upon compiling the frontend I would get the error **TypeError: http.ServerResponse is undefined**

I was using **npx create-react-app**  for creating react frontend and as a result some of the files are not compiled properly. when I used **create-react-app**  for creating react frontend it all got set!

So a better practice is to create your react app using **create-react-app**  instead of using **npx create-react-app**

Hope this helps!